# Unable to Update Eloquent datatables in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 Models in My Laravel App like Employee , Salary and Title. Employee Model one to Many Relationship with both Salary and Title Models. Now I need update  data using EmployeeController updateEmployee function
EmployeeController

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id) {
    $employee = Employee::find($id);
    $title = $employee->titles()->update($request->all);
    $salary = $employee->salaries()->update($request->all);
    if(is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }
    $employee->update($request->all());
    
    return response($employee, 200);

}
```

and my api route is following

```
Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@updateEmployee');
```

Employee Model

```
public function titles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_no');
}

public function salaries(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Salary Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Title Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

but when I try update I got following error message

> `TypeError: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update(): Argument #1 ($values) must be of type array, null given, called in F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23 in file F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1009`

How could I fix this matter?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicaties that you don't send any data to your API. (`$request->all()` is null).
That is because you don't verify if the requests contains any data.

You can validate the request using the `$request->validate()` method. More info about that in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic);

Alternatively you can use Laravel [form requests](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation).

Comment: but without `$title = $employee->titles()->update($request->all);
        $salary = $employee->salaries()->update($request->all);` titles and salaries update it is working

Comment: There is a typo in your code, it should be: `$request->all()`

Comment: now unable update Title and Salary Tables both same time. one of them possible

Comment: Debug the code. Check if the `$request->all()` does even have any variables (`dd($request->all()` or `echo $request->all()`).

Answer (score 0):

your data is null. check your route api. pass in your variable by array.

Comment: you mean may I need all table columns values before update?

Answer (score 0):

#### To solve the error

As some people already notice in comments, you should use `$request->all()` to get all the request params. But I recommend to never use it and filter the request with a [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation).

#### Future errors after using `$request->all()`

You are updating a `Has-Many` relationship but Eloquent doesn't know **which** model needs to be updated. This is for the **title** and **salary** relationships.

We don't know the logic behind esparate models for salary and title, but it could be just another column on the employees table. With this approach, you didn't need to worry about updating 3 separated models and just check for the fields inside the form request.

If you need to update an specific salary or title, you can add the route for this cases and their respective controller functions.

```php
Route::put(
  '/employees/{employee}/salaries/{salary}',
  [EmployeeSalaryController::class, 'update']);
Route::put(
  '/employees/{employee}/titles/{title}',
  [EmployeeTitleController::class, 'update']
);
```

Another option is to get those as attributes for the employee as I said before, and just use the route you already have with a few modifications on the controller.

Answer (score 0):

First you want to check if employee exists and then update salaries and titles like this:

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id) 
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id); // When the employee not found its return null value 

    if(!$employee) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Employee not found'
        ], 404);
    }

    $title = $employee->titles()->update($request->all);
    $salary = $employee->salaries()->update($request->all);
    $employee->update($request->all());
    return response($employee, 200);
}
```